# Problem using Observable with trackBy, how to update Observable<any[]>

Tags: angular, observable

as I saw in many tutorials, it is highly recommended to use native way of Angular if we are dealing with an observable service.
So I have a service like "ActionService" with a method:

```
findAll(): Observable {
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl)
}
```

My Component:
export class ActionCodesComponent {
actionCodes$: Observable

```
constructor(private actionService: ActionService) {
this.actionCodes$ = this.actionService.findAll();
}

onDelete() { // how should I refresh the Observable here???
this.actionCodes$ = this.actionService.findAll();
}

trackByActionCode(index, actionCode): string {
return actionCode ? actionCode.id : undefined
}
```

}
The first problem:
right now, if I delete an element from a list by clicking on "X" span, the whole list is being rendered again and flicking. So at first the trackBy function does not work (if I use the same function not with observable but with array of elements, it works very fine).

Second Problem: how can I update my Observable without recreation it again like

```
this.actionCodes$ = this.actionService.getAll()
```

?
All examples on youtube and internet showing like `myObservable = the Subject()` and `myObservable.next()`.
But it does bot work with my Observable `this.actionCodes$`. There is no next() method available at all.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here? If I cannot update a list using Observable (not an array), why it is recommended by every Angular expert?
Thanks

Comment: If you are using an `async` pipe with your `actionCodes$` maybe you will find that question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805203/trackby-with-the-async-pipe

Comment: About second question. `Subject` and `Observable` are often mistaken. With `Observable` you can only consume/get data. `Subject` on the other hand can both produce data (so `emit()`) and consume `subscribe()`.
[Here is thread about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537934/what-is-the-difference-between-observable-and-a-subject-in-rxjs)

Comment: That article you pointed I have already read. It is exactly what I can not repeat, it is recommended, that I use ..$.next(), which is not working in my case. Since I have no subject.